# Target group without Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

I am trying to understand an already existing aws architecture. There are some Target Groups without any Load Balancer associated with them.

Does it make sense to have a Target Group and not associate it with a Load Balancer?

Comment: Probably not, although I could see a use case for disabling certain targets or switching them between LBs (that's more of a dev-time thing, though). I would (1) look at the instances associated with the target groups to see if they've been receiving traffic, and (2) look at CloudTrail (event types `DeleteRule` and `ModifyRule`) to see who last changed the LB configuration (and then ask them why).

Comment: It depends..If the target groups are just EC2 instances(not only one) in each TG, then it wouldn't make any sense. in cotrary yes, why put a load balancer when you have only one EC2 instance to route traffic to. Also , if the target is a lambda, you wouldn't need an LB.